# Jars Dependencies - On the revision control or the continuous integration\build tool

Tags: git, version-control, build, continuous-integration, pom.xml

We have a web application with some Jars dependencies (similar to pom files).
What is the best practice for such file? :

1) To put it in the revision control (git) with the rest of the source code?
 (allowing developers to manipulate it easily according to development needs)

2) To put it on the continuous integration\build tool (jenkins)? (by this , making the jars dependencies resides on a single place, preventing the developers from changing the versions of the jars themselves)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of both.  If there is a need to modify an existing dependencies for development, then developers should be able to do that by checking out the source code.  However, once a version is committed to trunk it should be in one single place and should not be altered.  If a dependency is to be altered, then it should get a major/minor revision increase.